# AngularJS, load module

Tags: angularjs

First of all, i'm discovering AngularJS. I read many courses about it but i'm far from being familiar with it.

I have a project, were i cannot modify the previous declarations.
I want to add [wysiwyg](http://plnkr.co/edit/XMbvCtjIWWfddP5rpu5t) into the project.

I have to create an other controller using the existant module.
I know that if i redefine the module, previous will be lost.

I thought this would be good :

```
angular.module('demo')
  .controller('WysiwygCtrl', ['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      text: "hello"
    }
}]);
```

But it doesn't work.

In fact, the easiest way would be :

```
angular.module('demo', ['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module'])
  .controller('WysiwygCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      text: "hello"
    }
});
```

But it creates a new module and i loose previous one ...

How can i do to make it works ? If you need more code i can edit my question just ask but i think the module/controller is the most important part.

Thanks for you help, i'm facing this problem since this morning.

EDIT1 : The wysiwyg library is hosted on github here https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg

EDIT2 : Right now, nothing is displayed because i have the following error : 
`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=colorpicker.moduleProvider%20%3C-%20colorpicker.module`

Comment: So are you saying you want to access the wysiwyg.module within the WysiwygCtrl controller code?

Comment: @mindparse i don't know ... 
This code works : 
`var app = angular.module('app', ['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module'])

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    text: "hello"
  }
})` Now i'd like to know why mine isn't working

Comment: So what exactly is not working? Are you seeing the 'hello' appear in the wysiwyg editor?

Comment: You don't know? This is a really confusing question, can you share more of your codes

Comment: Ok i'm going to edit my post and give you more informations, thanks for the help

Comment: Edited. Also, i tried to put only the `angular.module('colorpicker.module', [])` and the `angular.module('wysiwyg.module', ['colorpicker.module'])`. I have no errors. As soon as i add the part `angular.module('demo')
  .controller('WysiwygCtrl', ['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module', function($scope) { ...` i get an error (edit2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.module('moduleName', ['dep1', 'dep2'])` - creates a module, that has dependencies listed in a second parameter, this signature also returns newly created module, you HAVE to specify list of dependencies, even if it's just an empty array `[]`. This also overwrites any existing modules by the same name.

`angular.module('moduleName')` - returns a module created earlier in your code, hence the absence of dependency list in the signature - this also returns a module.

both signatures allow you to add controllers, services, etc..

Comment: ok, but knowing that i can't modify the module before, is there a way to add dependencies ? `['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module']` ?

Comment: @Maxime - no, you have to specify all dependencies up front

Comment: Damn ... The best way would have been to declare the module, save it in a var and use that var after .... but here ? It's a big mess and i'm lost

Comment: yes, both signatures allow you to save module to a `var`, but you can't add more dependencies to an existing module.. and you don't need to!!

Comment: 'but you can add more dependencies to an existing module.. and you don't need to!!' what do you mean exactly ? Maybe you wanted to say "can't add" ? Otherwise i don't understand your previous comment " no, you have to specify all dependencies up front"

Comment: dark_ruby thx, i accepted your answer because i won't be able to do better ... I'll manage to reorganise the structure to be able to add my dependencies up front !

Comment: @Maxime glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Plus I think you need to be passing in references to them modules in the function

```
.controller('WysiwygCtrl', ['$scope', 'colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module', function($scope, colorpickermodule, wysiwygmodule) {
    $scope.data = {
      text: "hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: `Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=colorpicker.moduleProvider%20%3C-%20colorpicker.module`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the array notation when creating components as controllers or directives, then the parameters on the main function or module should match. As i see that you use

```
.controller('WysiwygCtrl', ['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module',   function($scope) {
$scope.data = {
  text: "hello"
}
```

you maybe want to say

```
.controller('WysiwygCtrl', ['$scope', 'colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module', function($scope) {
$scope.data = {
  text: "hello"
}
```

Comment: I tried to add the '$scope' but i still have an error : `Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=colorpicker.moduleProvider%20%3C-%20colorpicker.module`

Comment: It seens like it can't find the colorpicker.module service. You have to make sure that you declare it before trying to inject it into another component as a dependency