# Is there something wrong with my angularjs controller/module?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-blade

I am trying to build a view with a button that can add select-elements (for now).

Therefore the "FilterController.js" can add elements to its (here called filters) array.

````
    ```(function () {
        "use strict";
        angular.module('app').controller('FilterController', FilterController);

        function FilterController() {
            let ctrl = this;
            ctrl.filters = [];

            ctrl.addFilter = function () {
                ctrl.filters.push('filter' + ctrl.filters.length);
            }
        }
    }
)```
````

In the blade.view every item in the controller list should be displayed with a loop.

```
<div class="filter row" ng-controller="FilterController as ctrl">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">[['filter.filter' | translate]]</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form ng-repeat="item in ctrl.filters" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div>
                        <select class="select_[[item]]" ></select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.addFilter()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                <label for="button-label">[['filter.addFilter' | translate ]]</label>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This leads to a problem while build the app.js file. All the js is not not working in the browser.

Also there is this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module directives.select2 due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'directives.select2' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/nomod?p0=directives.select2
minErr/<@http://{{mylocalinstance}}/build/js/app-32003bf5e4.js:13328:12
setupModuleLoader/</module/<@http://{{mylocalinstance}}/build/js/app-32003bf5e4.js:15393:17
ensure@http://{{mylocalinstance}}/build/js/app-32003bf5e4.js:15317:38
module@http://{{mylocalinstance}}/build/js/app-32003bf5e4.js:15391:14
createInjector/loadModules/<@http:{{mylocalinstance}}/build/js/app-32003bf5e4.js:17929:22
forEach@http://{{mylocalinstance}}/build/js/app-32003bf5e4.js:13585:20
loadModules@http://{{mylocalinstance}}…
```

The error points out the registration of the module, but I didn't find some answers that could help me. ( [AngularJS, load module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431402/angularjs-load-module))

Thanks in advance. It also could be something very basic. I am quite new to angularJs. :)

EDIT: This error also shows up -

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
<anonymous> HostController.js:68
```

HostController.js:68
 HostController.js:68

Comment: Where is directives.select2? -- `Module 'directives.select2' is not available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it!

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('app').controller('FilterController', FilterController);

    function FilterController() {
        let ctrl = this;
        ctrl.filters = [];

        ctrl.addFilter = function () {
            ctrl.filters.push('filter' + ctrl.filters.length);
        }
    }
})();
```

The `();` at the end was missing to self-invoke the function above (witch is also placed in parentheses).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE